# Are updating, creation etc. functionalities of cloud functions affected by the firestore security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I have made several rules based on the userid so wanted to confirm that will these rules block the update done by the cloud functions written in nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cloud functions act as admin. See [How to make Firebase Functions act as a user instead of being an admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52176402/how-to-make-firebase-functions-act-as-a-user-instead-of-being-an-admin)

But there is a button in `Rules` tab called `Rules Playground` that you can use for testing your `firestore` rules.

Comment: I want functions to bipass security rules. Do i need to do anything?

Comment: Cloud functions always bypass any of the rules you made for your ```Firestore Database```. So if you want to bypass them, you do not have to do anything, but if you need your functions act with user permissions, you have to implement it yourself.